# pytorch skip connection in a sequential model

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, sequential

I am trying to wrap my head around skip connections in a sequential model. With the functional API I would be doing something as easy as (quick example, maybe not be 100% syntactically correct but should get the idea):

```python
x1 = self.conv1(inp)
x = self.conv2(x)
x = self.conv3(x)
x = self.conv4(x)

x = self.deconv4(x)
x = self.deconv3(x)
x = self.deconv2(x)
x = torch.cat((x, x1), 1))
x = self.deconv1(x)
```

I am now using a sequential model and trying to do something similar, create a skip connection that brings the activations of the first conv layer all the way to the last convTranspose. I have taken a look at the U-net architecture implemented [here](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix) and it's a bit confusing, it does something like this:

```python
upconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(inner_nc * 2, outer_nc,
                                    kernel_size=4, stride=2,
                                    padding=1, bias=use_bias)
down = [downrelu, downconv, downnorm]
up = [uprelu, upconv, upnorm]

if use_dropout:
    model = down + [submodule] + up + [nn.Dropout(0.5)]
else:
    model = down + [submodule] + up
```

Isn't this just adding layers to the sequential model well, sequentially? There is the `down` conv which is followed by `submodule` (which recursively adds inner layers) and then concatenated to `up` which is the upconv layer. I am probably missing something important on how the `Sequential` API works, but how does the code snipped from U-NET actually implements the skip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observations are correct, but you may have missed the definition of `UnetSkipConnectionBlock.forward()` (`UnetSkipConnectionBlock` being the `Module` defining the U-Net block you shared), which may clarify this implementation:

(from [`pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/models/networks.py#L259`](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/2ecf15f8a7f87fa56e784e0504136e9daf6b93d6/models/networks.py#L259))

```
# Defines the submodule with skip connection.
# X -------------------identity---------------------- X
#   |-- downsampling -- |submodule| -- upsampling --|
class UnetSkipConnectionBlock(nn.Module):

    # ...

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.outermost:
            return self.model(x)
        else:
            return torch.cat([x, self.model(x)], 1)
```

The last line is the key (applied for all inner blocks). The skip layer is simply done by concatenating the input `x` and the (recursive) block output `self.model(x)`, with `self.model` the list of operations you mentioned -- so not so differently from the `Functional` code you wrote.